# Report duplicate object keys

Tags: json, duplicates, key, jq

How do you use jq to detect and report duplicate object keys? For example, the following JSON has duplicate key on `.a`.

```
{
  "a":{
    "b": 1
  },
  "a":{
    "c": 1
  }
}
```

I think using --stream is required but I can't quite get it right.

Edit: cannot assume the dup can exist only as the top level key. The dup may exist at any level.

Comment: What is your desired output? An array of strings (the duplicate keys)? And on what levels should this work? Only on top level, or also on deeper ones (only if they collapse)?

Comment: Just a true or false indicating if there were dups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind running jq twice, you could produce the stream once "externally" (before collapsing duplicates) with the `--stream` flag, and once "internally" (after collapsing duplicates) with the `tostream` filter, and then `diff` their results (using `jq -c` further reduces the amount of output to diff):

```bash
diff -qs <(jq -c --stream . file.json) <(jq -c tostream file.json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an efficient solution for the case where there is exactly one top-level object.  It's efficient for several reasons, including that it's a jq-only solution (e.g., no need for `diff`), and that jq is only called once.

```
jq -n --stream '

# "bag of words"
def bow(stream): 
  reduce stream as $word ({}; .[($word|tostring)] += 1);

# Emit a stream of the duplicated items in the array
def duplicates:
   bow(.[]) | with_entries(select(.value > 1)) | keys_unsorted[];

# Duplicate keys of the top-level object
[inputs
 | select( (length == 1 and (.[0]|length==2)) or
           (length == 2 and (.[0]|length==1)) )
 | first|first ]
| duplicates
'
```

Output for the sample input:

```
"a"
```